# replace dictionary keys in DataFrame column with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary **col_dict** that matches a specific column with its definition:

```
{...,
'COL10': '20_Contract_size_for_derivatives',
 'COL11': '21_Quotation_currency_(A)',
 'COL12': '23_Clean_market_valuation_in_quotation_currency_(A)',
 'COL13': '24_Market_valuation_in_portfolio_currency_(B)',
 'COL14': '25_Clean_market_valuation_in_portfolio_currency_(B)',
 'COL15': '26_Valuation_weight',
...}
```

I want to use col_dict to replace each COL by its definition under column **ref_formula** in a **dependency** DataFrame:

```
  col_ref   ref_formula
46  COL45   COL11/COL14
53  COL52   COL10*COL12
55  COL54   COL13
56  COL55   COL263
57  COL56   COL265
```

Expected Output would be:

```
  col_ref   ref_formula
46  COL45   21_Quotation_currency_(A)/25_Clean_market_valuation_in_portfolio_currency_(B)
53  COL52   20_Contract_size_for_derivatives*23_Clean_market_valuation_in_quotation_currency_(A)
55  COL54   24_Market_valuation_in_portfolio_currency_(B)
```

I have managed to do that by converting **ref_formula** column into a string and then making the substitution with re:

```
import re
fin=str(dependency['ref_formula'])
fin = re.sub(r'\n[0-9][0-9]?','',fin)

def find_replace_multi_ordered(string, dictionary):
    for item in sorted(dictionary.keys(), key = len, reverse = True):
        string = re.sub(item, dictionary[item], string)
    return string
find_replace_multi_ordered(fin, col_dict)
```

However the output I get is a string and I do not manage to convert it back to the DataFrame or match it with the initial dependency DataFrame.

Any suggestion on how to make this substitutions directly under the DataFrame column? Or on how to join the resulting string back to the initial DataFrame?

Comment: Check `dependency['ref_formula'].replace(dictionary, regex=True)`

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ShubhamSharma! It seems to be working

Comment: The only problem is that it does not take into consideration the length of the dictionary key: basically if we have "COL125" in the text, it will just grab "COL1" and replace it (I've tried to avoid it by using that ordered logic in my code above).

Answer (score 0):

Create list of all your records and give them keys you wanted like that

```
new_dict=[]
for i in col_dict:
    new_dict.append({"col_ref": i, "ref_formula": col_dict[i]})
```

Then create dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
print(df)
```